# REST API SQL stored procedure conversion error (Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed)

Tags: sql-server, rest, stored-procedures, dreamfactory

I am using dreamfactory REST API to call a SQL Server stored procedure. The SQL Server database is using a user defined data type for a few of the parameters of the stored procedure.

Here is how I am calling it via the API Docs area of Dreamfactory:

```
 {
 "params": [
      {
      "name": "Number",
      "param_type": "IN",
      "value": "123456"
      },
      {
      "name": "IdNumber",
      "param_type": "IN",
      "value": "0x0048F1F5A7DC5A2A431CBAD70270E59C5FA0"
     }
 ],
 "schema": {
 "_field_name_": ""
  },
 "wrapper": "",
 "returns": ""
  }
```

The error is:

> Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed

I believe the problem is with the second parameter `IdNumber` which is the user-defined data type. If I delete the parameter I just get an error that `IdNumber` is expected and missing.

The data type is a user defined type and I am not sure why it is trying to convert it to `varbinary`. I don't really know of any way to convert or store the value since it's using the REST API. Am I correct in thinking that I cannot cast or convert anything as a stored procedure parameter?

I know this is a pretty specific problem but any help is appreciated. I have been fighting with dreamfactor a lot on this project and if the answer is to go in another direction I am open to that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason that it's trying to convert it to varbinary is this:

```
"value": "0x0048F1F5A7DC5A2A431CBAD70270E59C5FA0"
```

I believe the leading 0x in the value is triggering it.  Typically, a value that starts with 0x is considered a Hexadecimal value.

I am not familiar with MS SQL Server, however, if you do not intend to allow the user defined data type to be binary, perhaps you could filter the input to not allow a leading 0x.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

After working with Dreamfactory tech support this is an issue with Dreamfactory that they hope to have resolved soon.